# /usr/local subdirectories allowed?

Tags: fhs

I'm currently having some conflicted doubts about the `/usr/local` folder according to the standard.

In our application, we currently store our read-only application files in `/usr/local/<appname>`. While going through the [Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/FHS_3.0/fhs/ch04s09.html) it noted that no other directories may be in `/usr/local` other than those listed.

Another [user on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34166003/9398242) quoted a text specifying that `/usr/local/<appname>` is supposed to be used, but I'm unable to find this part in the FHS.

Other examples I've seen on my machine are `/usr/local/mysql` and `/usr/local/percona`.

Are these simply not in line with the standard? Should we be switching to `/usr/local/share/<appname>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Are these simply not in line with the standard? Should we be switching to `/usr/local/share/<appname>`?

Yep, you should. That would make the local installation hierarchically "compatible" with a system installation, which would also not put the data in /usr, but /usr/share.